# Is VirtualAlloc alignment consistent with size of allocation?

Tags: winapi, virtual-memory

When using the `VirtualAlloc` API to allocate and commit a region of virtual memory with a power of two size of the page boundary such as:

```
void* address = VirtualAlloc(0, 0x10000, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE); // Get 64KB
```

The `address` seems to always be in 64KB alignment, not just the page boundary, which in my case is 4KB.

The question is: Is this alignment reliable and prescribed, or is it just coincidence?  [The docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366887%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) state that it is guaranteed to be on a page boundary, but does not address the behavior I'm seeing. I ask because I'd later like to take an arbitrary pointer (provided by a pool allocator that uses this chunk) and determine which 64KB chunk it belongs to by something similar to:

```
void* chunk = (void*)((uintptr_t)ptr & 0xFFFF0000);
```

Comment: I'm choosing llnspectable as the answer as he/she clarified the docs quite well.  But @Hans I will take another look at the Heap* functions, I can't remember why I went down the Virtual* path over the Heap functions, but now that you've both helped me understand it a little better, my choice might change.  Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The documentation for [`VirtualAlloc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366887.aspx) describes the behavior for 2 scenarios: 1) Reserving memory and 2) Committing memory:

> If the memory is being **reserved**, the specified address is rounded down to the nearest multiple of the **allocation granularity**.
>
> If the memory is already reserved and is being **committed**, the address is rounded down to the next **page boundary**.

In other words, memory is allocated (reserved) in multiples of the allocation granularity and committed in multiples of a page size. If you are reserving and committing memory in a single step, it will be be aligned at a multiple of the allocation granularity. When committing already reserved memory it will be aligned at a page boundary.

To query a system's page size and allocation granularity, call [`GetSystemInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724381.aspx). The [`SYSTEM_INFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724958.aspx) structure's `dwPageSize` and `dwAllocationGranularity` will hold the page size and allocation granularity, respectively.

Comment: You answered my sub question to Hans while I was typing it, thanks!

Comment: Since it is not possible to commit without reserving (either in two steps, or in one), doesn't that mean that unless you first reserve, and then _deliberately request a smaller region starting at a different address_, the address is necessarily aligned to the allocation granularity? It has to be for reserving, anyway.

Comment: @Damon: Reserving large chunks of address space and then committing smaller regions of memory is a common pattern, and one of the main reasons, why you would reserve and commit memory as two distinct operations. But yes, committed memory can be aligned at allocation granularity boundaries. That's no more enlightening than saying, that some multiples of 4 are also multiples of 64, though.

Comment: @Damon This is actually not true. It *is* possible to successfully commit without reserving. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20151008-00/?p=91411

Comment: Just pointing out that technically, the section about rounding "down to the nearest multiple of the allocation granularity" only applies to the lpAddress parameter. So if you pass in 0 for that parameter, which you usually do when reserving memory (because you don't know what addresses are available), that section doesn't apply. I sincerily hope it still applies in practice, but the docs don't guarantee it.

Answer (score 5):

This is entirely normal.  64KB is the value of SYSTEM_INFO.dwAllocationGranularity.  It is a simple counter-measure against address space fragmentation, 4KB pages are too small.  The memory manager will still sub-divide 64KB chunks as needed if you change page protection of individual pages within the chunk.

Use HeapAlloc() to sub-allocate.  The heap manager has specific counter-measures against fragmentation.

Comment: Thanks Hans!  I'm sorry if this is a silly question, but if you could indulge my curiosity.  Granularity is applicable to the address of the allocation and page size would be applicable to size of that allocation?  If this is true, would you then be "wasting space" by allocating anything less than the granularity? It would seem that addresses greater than the size, but less than the next granularity would become unobtainable.  So a fair rule of thumb might be to reserve multiples of granularity and commit multiples of page size?

Comment: Yes, allocating a size that's not a multiple of the granularity is wasting address space.  Not exactly a great problem, it is virtual and there's a lot of it.  Using VirtualAlloc yourself isn't a great idea, best to leave it up to HeapAlloc and friends.

Comment: Legacy reasons, to make Alpha AXP relocations simpler.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031008-00/?p=42223/

Comment: I think the most important reason for having allocation granularity is to ease development of architecture-independent software working under Windows. Allocation granularity basically acts as virtual page size that is platform independent. That is why not only memory allocations are affected by it, but also memory mapped files - mapped region offset should be multiple of allocation granularity. I am sure that internally Windows does not store page cache in 64kb aligned chunks - too wasteful.